# Difference between source and './' with respect to permissions in bash?

Tags: macos, shell, permissions, terminal

I have a simple executable shell file `testperm.sh` with permissions `-rw-------@`.

When I execute `source testperm.sh` or `. testperm.sh`, the file executes and prints `Hello...........`, as it should.

However, if I run `./testperm.sh`, I get `-bash: ./testperm.sh: Permission denied`. Why is that permission is denied with this command, but with `source` it works fine?

(I'm referring to the bash shell on OS X by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `source testperm.sh`/`. testperm.sh` and `./testperm.sh` is like the difference between `ls /bin/bash` and `/bin/bash`.

The former in each pair is using the file as an *argument* to some other command.

The latter in each pair is using the file as the *command* to run.

Running a command requires executable permission. Using a file as an argument does not.

Comment: So I guess my question would be.... how does source work internally such that it can access the file and is there any way you can `chmod` to deny it permission?

Comment: It reads the file. The same way `cat` or anything else does. If you don't have permission to read the file then they won't work.